# Building simple OpenGL program with Eclipse mingw-w64 on win7 64bit make error

Tags: eclipse, compilation, cmake, glfw, mingw-w64

I am trying to build a simple sample OPENGL program opengl-tutorial.org, followed their instruction in [tutorial 1](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/), but using Eclipse.

Downloaded their source code, compiled with cmake, option Eclipse-CDT4 MinGW Makefiles, made a project. Then I imported it into Eclipse workspace. Everything worked fine until then, but when I try to build the whole project, I found that it somehow does not compile / make libglfw3.a.

It produced mingw32-make error rooting to `mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'src/libglfw3.a', needed by 'examples/boing.exe'.  Stop. GLFW@glfw-build         C/C++ Problem`

I later downloaded the source package from [glfw.org](http://www.glfw.org/download.html), (which I see opengl-tutorial.org seemed to have just included glfw.org source code into their own bundle) and followed its tutorial while trying the same compile method, only compiling glfw, it also returned the same error.

would want to know if anyone has some idea towards why this happens.

I am using

- Eclipse Cpp Mars 4.5.1
- mingw-w64 5.1.0 (from mingw-w64.sourceforge.net)
- cmake 3.5.0
- Windows 7 64 bit ultimate

The compilation goes as far as

```
  [ 19%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/boing.c.obj
cd /d D:\glfw\glfw-build\examples && D:\mingw64\install\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe  -DUNICODE -DWINVER=0x0501 @CMakeFiles/boing.dir/includes_C.rsp  -o CMakeFiles\boing.dir\boing.c.obj   -c D:\project-y-dev\glfw\glfw-3.1.2\examples\boing.c
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/development/eclipse_cpp_x64/workspace/GLFW@glfw-build'
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'src/libglfw3.a', needed by 'examples/boing.exe'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:183: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/all' failed
```

The cmake generated output

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
Could not determine Eclipse version, assuming at least 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.
Check for working C compiler: D:/mingw64/install/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: D:/mingw64/install/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features - done
Found OpenGL: opengl32  
Looking for pthread.h - found
Looking for pthread_create - found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Found Doxygen: C:/Program Files/doxygen/bin/doxygen.exe (found version "1.8.11") 
Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_DEP - Success
Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_ASLR - Success
Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_64ASLR - Success
Using Win32 for window creation
Using WGL for context creation
Configuring done
```

@Mike Kinghan

Thankyou for your response, I will post the CMakeLists.txt here, its a 19KB text file

Its also available on the glfw github https : //github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

sorry stackoverflow does not allow me to post more than 2 links, github link is broken

```
project(GLFW C)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.0")
    # Until all major package systems have moved to CMake 3,
    # we stick with the older INSTALL_NAME_DIR mechanism
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0042 OLD)
endif()

set(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR "3")
set(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set(GLFW_VERSION_PATCH "2")
set(GLFW_VERSION_EXTRA "")
set(GLFW_VERSION "${GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR}.${GLFW_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(GLFW_VERSION_FULL "${GLFW_VERSION}.${GLFW_VERSION_PATCH}${GLFW_VERSION_EXTRA}")
set(LIB_SUFFIX "" CACHE STRING "Takes an empty string or 64. Directory where lib will be installed: lib or lib64")

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)
option(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build the GLFW example programs" ON)
option(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS "Build the GLFW test programs" ON)
option(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS "Build the GLFW documentation" ON)
option(GLFW_INSTALL "Generate installation target" ON)
option(GLFW_DOCUMENT_INTERNALS "Include internals in documentation" OFF)

if (WIN32)
    option(GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG "Force use of high-performance GPU on hybrid systems" OFF)
endif()

if (APPLE)
    option(GLFW_BUILD_UNIVERSAL "Build GLFW as a Universal Binary" OFF)
    option(GLFW_USE_CHDIR "Make glfwInit chdir to Contents/Resources" ON)
    option(GLFW_USE_MENUBAR "Populate the menu bar on first window creation" ON)
    option(GLFW_USE_RETINA "Use the full resolution of Retina displays" ON)
else()
    option(GLFW_USE_EGL "Use EGL for context creation" OFF)
endif()

if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    option(GLFW_USE_WAYLAND "Use Wayland for context creation (implies EGL as well)" OFF)
    option(GLFW_USE_MIR     "Use Mir for context creation (implies EGL as well)" OFF)
endif()

if (MSVC)
    option(USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL "Use MSVC runtime library DLL" ON)
endif()

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    set(_GLFW_BUILD_DLL 1)
endif()

if (GLFW_USE_WAYLAND)
    set(GLFW_USE_EGL ON)
elseif (GLFW_USE_MIR)
    set(GLFW_USE_EGL ON)
endif()

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/modules")

if (GLFW_USE_EGL)
    set(GLFW_CLIENT_LIBRARY "opengl" CACHE STRING
        "The client library to use; one of opengl, glesv1 or glesv2")

    if (${GLFW_CLIENT_LIBRARY} STREQUAL "opengl")
        set(_GLFW_USE_OPENGL 1)
    elseif (${GLFW_CLIENT_LIBRARY} STREQUAL "glesv1")
        set(_GLFW_USE_GLESV1 1)
    elseif (${GLFW_CLIENT_LIBRARY} STREQUAL "glesv2")
        set(_GLFW_USE_GLESV2 1)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported client library")
    endif()

    find_package(EGL REQUIRED)

    if (NOT _GLFW_USE_OPENGL)
        set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
        set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
        message(STATUS "NOTE: Examples and tests require OpenGL")
    endif()
else()
    set(_GLFW_USE_OPENGL 1)
endif()

if (_GLFW_USE_OPENGL)
    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
elseif (_GLFW_USE_GLESV1)
    find_package(GLESv1 REQUIRED)
elseif (_GLFW_USE_GLESV2)
    find_package(GLESv2 REQUIRED)
endif()

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

if (GLFW_BUILD_DOCS)
    set(DOXYGEN_SKIP_DOT TRUE)
    find_package(Doxygen)

    if (GLFW_DOCUMENT_INTERNALS)
        set(GLFW_INTERNAL_DOCS "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/src/internal.h ${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/internal.dox")
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set compiler specific flags
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (UNIX)
    add_definitions(-Wall)

    if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
        add_definitions(-fvisibility=hidden)
    endif()
endif()

if (MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)

    if (NOT USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL)
        foreach (flag CMAKE_C_FLAGS
                        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
                        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
                        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
                        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)

            if (${flag} MATCHES "/MD")
                string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag} "${${flag}}")
            endif()
            if (${flag} MATCHES "/MDd")
                string(REGEX REPLACE "/MDd" "/MTd" ${flag} "${${flag}}")
            endif()

        endforeach()
    endif()
endif()

if (MINGW)
    # Enable link-time exploit mitigation features enabled by default on MSVC
    include(CheckCCompilerFlag)

    # Compatibility with data execution prevention (DEP)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-Wl,--nxcompat")
    check_c_compiler_flag("" _GLFW_HAS_DEP)
    if (_GLFW_HAS_DEP)
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--nxcompat ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()

    # Compatibility with address space layout randomization (ASLR)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-Wl,--dynamicbase")
    check_c_compiler_flag("" _GLFW_HAS_ASLR)
    if (_GLFW_HAS_ASLR)
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--dynamicbase ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()

    # Compatibility with 64-bit address space layout randomization (ASLR)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-Wl,--high-entropy-va")
    check_c_compiler_flag("" _GLFW_HAS_64ASLR)
    if (_GLFW_HAS_64ASLR)
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--high-entropy-va ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()

    # HACK: When building on MinGW, WINVER and UNICODE need to be defined before
    # the inclusion of stddef.h (by glfw3.h), which is itself included before
    # win32_platform.h.  We define them here until a saner solution can be found
    # NOTE: MinGW-w64 and Visual C++ do /not/ need this hack.
    add_definitions(-DUNICODE -DWINVER=0x0501)
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Detect and select backend APIs
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (WIN32)
    set(_GLFW_WIN32 1)
    message(STATUS "Using Win32 for window creation")

    if (GLFW_USE_EGL)
        set(_GLFW_EGL 1)
        message(STATUS "Using EGL for context creation")
    else()
        set(_GLFW_WGL 1)
        message(STATUS "Using WGL for context creation")
    endif()
elseif (APPLE)
    set(_GLFW_COCOA 1)
    message(STATUS "Using Cocoa for window creation")
    set(_GLFW_NSGL 1)
    message(STATUS "Using NSGL for context creation")
elseif (UNIX)
    if (GLFW_USE_WAYLAND)
        set(_GLFW_WAYLAND 1)
        message(STATUS "Using Wayland for window creation")
    elseif (GLFW_USE_MIR)
        set(_GLFW_MIR 1)
        message(STATUS "Using Mir for window creation")
    else()
        set(_GLFW_X11 1)
        message(STATUS "Using X11 for window creation")
    endif()

    if (GLFW_USE_EGL)
        set(_GLFW_EGL 1)
        message(STATUS "Using EGL for context creation")
    else()
        set(_GLFW_GLX 1)
        message(STATUS "Using GLX for context creation")
    endif()
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "No supported platform was detected")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find and add Unix math and time libraries
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    find_library(RT_LIBRARY rt)
    mark_as_advanced(RT_LIBRARY)
    if (RT_LIBRARY)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${RT_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lrt")
    endif()

    find_library(MATH_LIBRARY m)
    mark_as_advanced(MATH_LIBRARY)
    if (MATH_LIBRARY)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${MATH_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lm")
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Win32 for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_WIN32)

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lgdi32")

    if (GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG)
        set(_GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG 1)
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use WGL for context creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_WGL)

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lopengl32")

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use X11 for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_X11)

    find_package(X11 REQUIRED)

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "x11")

    # Set up library and include paths
    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_X11_LIB}" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")

    # Check for XRandR (modern resolution switching and gamma control)
    if (NOT X11_Xrandr_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The RandR library and headers were not found")
    endif()

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_Xrandr_INCLUDE_PATH}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_Xrandr_LIB}")
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xrandr")

    # Check for Xinerama (legacy multi-monitor support)
    if (NOT X11_Xinerama_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The Xinerama library and headers were not found")
    endif()

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_Xinerama_INCLUDE_PATH}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_Xinerama_LIB}")
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xinerama")

    # Check for XInput (high-resolution cursor motion)
    if (X11_Xinput_FOUND)
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_Xinput_INCLUDE_PATH}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xi")

        if (X11_Xinput_LIB)
            list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_Xinput_LIB}")
        else()
            # Backwards compatibility (bug in CMake 2.8.7)
            list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES Xi)
        endif()

        set(_GLFW_HAS_XINPUT TRUE)
    endif()

    # Check for Xf86VidMode (fallback gamma control)
    if (X11_xf86vmode_FOUND)
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_xf86vmode_INCLUDE_PATH}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xxf86vm")

        if (X11_Xxf86vm_LIB)
            list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_Xxf86vm_LIB}")
        else()
            # Backwards compatibility (see CMake bug 0006976)
            list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES Xxf86vm)
        endif()

        set(_GLFW_HAS_XF86VM TRUE)
    endif()

    # Check for Xkb (X keyboard extension)
    if (NOT X11_Xkb_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The X keyboard extension headers were not found")
    endif()

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIR "${X11_Xkb_INCLUDE_PATH}")

    # Check for Xcursor
    if (NOT X11_Xcursor_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The Xcursor libraries and headers were not found")
    endif()

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIR "${X11_Xcursor_INCLUDE_PATH}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_Xcursor_LIB}")
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xcursor")

endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Wayland for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_WAYLAND)
    find_package(Wayland REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "wayland-egl")

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${WAYLAND_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${WAYLAND_LIBRARIES}" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")

    find_package(XKBCommon REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xkbcommon")
    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${XKBCOMMON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${XKBCOMMON_LIBRARY}")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Mir for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_MIR)
    find_package(Mir REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "mirclient")

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${MIR_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${MIR_LIBRARIES}" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")

    find_package(XKBCommon REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "xkbcommon")
    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${XKBCOMMON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${XKBCOMMON_LIBRARY}")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use GLX for context creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_GLX)

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}")

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "gl")

    if (CMAKE_DL_LIBS)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-l${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use EGL for context creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_EGL)

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${EGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${EGL_LIBRARY}")

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "egl")

    if (_GLFW_USE_OPENGL)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "gl")
    elseif (_GLFW_USE_GLESV1)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${GLESv1_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GLESv1_INCLUDE_DIR}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "glesv1_cm")
    elseif (_GLFW_USE_GLESV2)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${GLESv2_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GLESv2_INCLUDE_DIR}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "glesv2")
    endif()

    if (CMAKE_DL_LIBS)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-l${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
    endif()

endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Cocoa for window creation and NSOpenGL for context creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_COCOA AND _GLFW_NSGL)

    if (GLFW_USE_MENUBAR)
        set(_GLFW_USE_MENUBAR 1)
    endif()

    if (GLFW_USE_CHDIR)
        set(_GLFW_USE_CHDIR 1)
    endif()

    if (GLFW_USE_RETINA)
        set(_GLFW_USE_RETINA 1)
    endif()

    if (GLFW_BUILD_UNIVERSAL)
        message(STATUS "Building GLFW as Universal Binaries")
        set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES i386;x86_64)
    else()
        message(STATUS "Building GLFW only for the native architecture")
    endif()

    # Set up library and include paths
    find_library(COCOA_FRAMEWORK Cocoa)
    find_library(IOKIT_FRAMEWORK IOKit)
    find_library(CORE_FOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK CoreFoundation)
    find_library(CORE_VIDEO_FRAMEWORK CoreVideo)
    mark_as_advanced(COCOA_FRAMEWORK
                     IOKIT_FRAMEWORK
                     CORE_FOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK
                     CORE_VIDEO_FRAMEWORK)
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${COCOA_FRAMEWORK}"
                               "${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}"
                               "${IOKIT_FRAMEWORK}"
                               "${CORE_FOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK}"
                               "${CORE_VIDEO_FRAMEWORK}")

    set(glfw_PKG_DEPS "")
    set(glfw_PKG_LIBS "-framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreVideo")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Export GLFW library dependencies
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
set(GLFW_LIBRARIES ${glfw_LIBRARIES} CACHE STRING "Dependencies of GLFW")
foreach(arg ${glfw_PKG_DEPS})
    set(GLFW_PKG_DEPS "${GLFW_PKG_DEPS} ${arg}")
endforeach()
foreach(arg ${glfw_PKG_LIBS})
    set(GLFW_PKG_LIBS "${GLFW_PKG_LIBS} ${arg}")
endforeach()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Choose library output name
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND UNIX)
    # On Unix-like systems, shared libraries can use the soname system.
    set(GLFW_LIB_NAME glfw)
else()
    set(GLFW_LIB_NAME glfw3)
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create generated files
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

if (UNIX)
    set(GLFW_CONFIG_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/glfw3/")
else()
    set(GLFW_CONFIG_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/")
endif()

configure_package_config_file("${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/src/glfw3Config.cmake.in"
                              "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3Config.cmake"
                              INSTALL_DESTINATION "${GLFW_CONFIG_PATH}"
                              PATH_VARS CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
                              NO_CHECK_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS_MACRO)

write_basic_package_version_file("${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake" 
                                 VERSION ${GLFW_VERSION_FULL}
                                 COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

if (GLFW_BUILD_DOCS)
    configure_file("${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/Doxyfile.in"
                   "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/docs/Doxyfile" @ONLY)
endif()

configure_file("${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/src/glfw_config.h.in"
               "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw_config.h" @ONLY)

configure_file("${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/src/glfw3.pc.in"
               "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3.pc" @ONLY)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add subdirectories
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
add_subdirectory(src)

if (GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    add_subdirectory(examples)
endif()

if (GLFW_BUILD_TESTS)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND AND GLFW_BUILD_DOCS)
    add_subdirectory(docs)
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install files other than the library
# The library is installed by src/CMakeLists.txt
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (GLFW_INSTALL)
    install(DIRECTORY include/GLFW DESTINATION include
            FILES_MATCHING PATTERN glfw3.h PATTERN glfw3native.h)

    install(FILES "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3Config.cmake"
                  "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake"
            DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/cmake/glfw)

    install(EXPORT glfwTargets DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/cmake/glfw)
    install(FILES "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3.pc"
            DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/pkgconfig)

    # Only generate this target if no higher-level project already has
    if (NOT TARGET uninstall)
        configure_file("${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in"
                       "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake" IMMEDIATE @ONLY)

        add_custom_target(uninstall
                          "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P
                          "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake")
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: The failing compiler commandline looks like nonsense but it's impossible to tell what you've done wrong without seeing your `CMakeLists` file.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Hi Mike, the CMakeLists is posted, I noticed that it states     # HACK: When building on MinGW, WINVER and UNICODE need to be defined before
    # the inclusion of stddef.h (by glfw3.h), which is itself included before
    # win32_platform.h.  We define them here until a saner solution can be found
    # NOTE: MinGW-w64 and Visual C++ do /not/ need this hack.

But I am unsure if it is related